# VS2019 Azure Function Solution organization

Tags: azure-functions, visual-studio-2019

Dumb question. In my Solution named FooSolution, I have a Project named FooReceivers. It's Azure WebHook project. Several of them actually for a specific form from a 3rd party website that will send JSON data. It's already deployed to Azure, successfully receiving JSON data and storing it in an Azure Message Queue.  I have all my "Queue Processors" code debugged and working properly. Except, I have them all in a second project I added to the existing solution. It's name is FooProcessors and the project's Publish to Azure configuration is exactly the same as FooReceivers.

So my question is, which is better?

1. Two separate projects in the same solution. To delineate or have demarcation.
2. Have Receivers and Processors code in the first project keeping the solution down to just one project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use the second way. Azure function can scale out, so there is no need to create two same function, azure function will automatically scale out instances.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate you taking the time to provide an opinion. A single solution with single project it is then.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd back track and supply the answer I discovered today to be the good working answer. Although I did upvote and mark Bowman's answer previously, I did follow his suggestion and my deployment was good but it broke everything. My previously working WebHooks was no longer functioning and I kept getting the error, ""Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60""

To make a very long story short, Source Code Version Control was my savior. I went into my "(WebHook Receivers" project and reverted back to a version from two days prior that had for the past weeks been working flawlessly for just the Webhook activities, redeployed to Azure and my 3rd party website that sends JSON data confirmed the integration was working again. Peek in the Azure Message Queue gave the second confirmation. Then I went back into my second project for the QueueTrigger Processors, deployed it to a new Function App container in Azure (to keep it apart from the WebHook Receivers), and all the confirmations showed it was working. Last visual confirmation was seeing all the data sitting in the Azure message queue had successfully transferred to our SharePoint 365 Lists.

The lesson to walk away with from my experience is, keep WebHooks and Message Queue data processing activities apart in their own Azure Function Apps. Especially, if the queue data processing project introduces SharePoint processing (CSOM) as part of its purpose. Apparently, the assemblies that pertain to WebHook processing in Azure are very sensitive and do not play well with the assemblies you need for other targets like SharePoint 365.